# Page not found - flutter web

Tags: flutter

I deployed the flutter web to firebase, whenever I try to access [www.example.com/username](http://www.example.com/username), it results into "page not found" whereas it works perfectly in localhost

I'm basically taking username from the path parameter (username) and pass it to the home page

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  AppRouter.setupRouter();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class AppRouter {
  static FluroRouter router = FluroRouter();

  static final usersHandler = Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, dynamic> parameters) {
    return Home(username: parameters['username'][0]);
  });


  static void setupRouter(){
    router.define("/:username", handler: usersHandler);
  }

}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  const Home({Key? key, required this.username}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User').where('username', isEqualTo: widget.username).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                BioModel bioModel = BioModel.fromMap(snapshot.data!.docs[0].data());
                return Column();
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xff16083A)));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What error did you get? What's inside parameters variable?

Comment: No error, when I try to access the url with path parameter, it results into page not found @AlejandroCumpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a correct firebase.json file, something like this?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I’m having the same code in Firebase.Json

Comment: my bad, yes, you were right! there wasn't rewrite object in firebase.json file